# Windows' custom boot logo started to show up on boot

Tags: kernel, boot, windows, dual-boot

I ran sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-* which started to remove many packages from my system(I wasn't paying attention to REGEX). I quickly realized what's happening, so I interrupted the process. Then I opened logs to see which packages did I just remove and started to reinstall them. As I am using Pop!_OS(which is based on Ubuntu) I found out that not only some gnome packages were missing but pop-desktop was missing as well. While pop-desktop was installing I saw Kernel building messages and so on... After the process was done, all of the missing packages were back. I, then, restarted my PC and suddenly I saw "ASUS Persistent perfection" logo, which was a thing only for Windows(I am using dual-boot). So my question is how could it happen and how can I fix this. By the way both bootloaders were installed on different partitions of the disk.

My guess it is because default grub settings were overwritten.

Comment: You are probably now EFI booting instead of using the BIOS method. When booting via UEFI, the vendor logo aka ASUS is shown. I think that it can be turned off. You can either revert to booting with BIOS (it might be as simple as selecting the drive in the boot menu instead of the uefi entry) or keep using UEFI (both should work just fine).

Comment: @rudib That seems unlikely. It world require a setting change in the BIOS which the OP hasn't explicitly done.

Comment: I'll just add a note that I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 19.10. after the change something is now different where it shows the Intel splash screen after the grub menu instead of an Ubuntu splash screen. It even overlays the cryptsetup password box on that same screen.

Comment: I don't know about Pop or Ubuntu for sure, but on fedora it only shows the vendor when uefi booting (as far as i recall).

Comment: I'm still not sure about the uefi-association, but I'm not the only one that made that connection: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/al1ie1/why_does_fedora_use_the_oem_boot_logo_rather_than/

Comment: TL;DR If you just want to change the boot sceen, you can try checking [the alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/a/2292/834547). Unfortunately, I can't test this as I don't have Ubuntu or Pop at hand.

Comment: The OEM splash screen is a (new-ish) plymouth feature: omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/03/ubuntu-20-04-oem-boot-splash